# CSS3 Opening Book effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have created an opening book with four pages.  This uses CSS3 only (at the moment).  I have added animation where the book opens after 2 seconds, then subsequently a few pages flip over.

Here is the example:
http://codepen.io/doolz77/full/amkgr/

What I am trying to create is

1. When someone clicks on a page no. it take them to the relative page.
2. After they have selected and read the page, they can then navigate to the next or previous page
3. Or they can click on 'contents' and it then take them back to the front page.

How would I go about doing this?  Would I need javascript?  Any help would be very much appreciated!

THanks!!

Comment: what you have tried???

Comment: Yes, use JavaScript.  If you aren't familiar with JavaScript, I'd suggest searching for some tutorials to help get you started.

Comment: I tried combining a Turn.js http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs/4 with my existing creation but got a little frustrated as not too great with javascript :(